How to solve "Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema"?
My database schema is not accepting my entity class even if it's true.
I rearragned my entity clas following the error message but it's not working
this is the error message that im getting:
Expected:
  TableInfo{name='activities', columns={activityId=Column{name='activityId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='undefined'}, emojiId=Column{name='emojiId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, visibility=Column{name='visibility', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, act_label=Column{name='act_label', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, latitude=Column{name='latitude', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, ownerId=Column{name='ownerId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, title=Column{name='title', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, act_date=Column{name='act_date', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, act_location=Column{name='act_location', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, desc=Column{name='desc', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, longitude=Column{name='longitude', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}}, foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='user', onDelete='CASCADE +', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[ownerId], referenceColumnNames=[id]}], indices=[]}
Found:
  TableInfo{name='activities', columns={activityId=Column{name='acti vityId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='undefined'}, ownerId=Column{name='ownerId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, title=Column{name='title', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, desc=Column{name='desc', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, visibility=Column{name='visibility', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, latitude=Column{name='latitude', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, longitude=Column{name='longitude', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, emojiId=Column{name='emojiId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}}, foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='user', onDelete='NO ACTION +', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[ownerId], referenceColumnNames=[id]}], indices=[]}
    at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onCreate(RoomOpenHelper.kt:73)

This is the schema:

This is the my entity class:
@Entity(
    tableName = "activities",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Users::class, // Assuming your user entity class is named User
            parentColumns = ["id"],
            childColumns = ["ownerId"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE, // Correct onDelete action
        )
    ]
)
data class Activities(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)val activityId: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "ownerId") val ownerId: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title") @NotNull val title: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "desc") val desc: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "visibility") val visibility: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "latitude")  val latitude: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "longitude")  val longitude: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "emojiId") val emojiId: Int?,
    @Ignore val actLabel: String, // New column
    @Ignore val actDate: Int, // New column
    @Ignore @NotNull val actLocation: String, // New column
) : Serializable


The Issue
Room expects (requires) a pre-packaged database to conform to the schema that Room generates; which is according to the @Entity annotated classes that are specified via the entities parameter of the @Database annotation of the class used for the database. Room is not very forgiving and has both implied and explicit expectations.

nullability or not is often implicit, with Kotlin a field without an ? implicity requires a NOT NULL constraint as does a Primary key field.

sometimes it is not possible to manipulate an @Entity annotated class to suit an existing schema. As such it is always recommended to not to try this approach but to instead manipulate an existing schema to suit Room's requirements. This, as is shown below, is relatively easy as Room generates the SQL for creating the expected components.


The message when interpreted/inspected shows the following:-

The activityId column in the pre-packaged database is not the same column name it is instead activity Id (the space).
The visibility column of the prepackaged database does not have the NOT NULL constraint.
Additionally the visibility column of the prepackaged database does NOT NULL constraint.
There is no act_label column in the prepackaged database.
The latitude column of the prepackaged database does not have the NOT NULL constraint.
There is no act_date column in the prepackaged database.
There is no act_location column in the prepackaged database.
The longitude column of the prepackaged database does not have the NOT NULL constraint.
The ON DELETE action of the prepackaged database's foreign key definition is NO ACTION. The Room database's ON DELETE action is CASCADE.

The above is ascertained by using a text editor to place the columns together as per (comments added):-
activityId=Column{name='activityId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='undefined'
activityId=Column{name='acti vityId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='undefined' /* BAD NAME DIFF also no NOT NULL */

emojiId=Column{name='emojiId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}
emojiId=Column{name='emojiId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'} /* GOOD */

visibility=Column{name='visibility', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}
visibility=Column{name='visibility', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'} /* BAD no NOT NULL */

act_label=Column{name='act_label', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'} /* BAD NO SUCH COL */


latitude=Column{name='latitude', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}
latitude=Column{name='latitude', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'} /* BAD no NOT NULL */

ownerId=Column{name='ownerId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}
ownerId=Column{name='ownerId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'} /* GOOD */

title=Column{name='title', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}
title=Column{name='title', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'} /* GOOD */

act_date=Column{name='act_date', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'} /* BAD NO SUCH COL */

act_location=Column{name='act_location', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'} /* BAD NO SUCH COL */


desc=Column{name='desc', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}
desc=Column{name='desc', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'} /* GOOD */


longitude=Column{name='longitude', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}
longitude=Column{name='longitude', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'} /* BAD no NOT NULL */


onDelete='CASCADE
onDelete='NO ACTION

The message obviously also does not match the Activities class provided in the question. Rather, the class, appears to be an attempt to alter the class to suit the schema (as suggested this is probably not the best way).
In the case of the altering the Activities class to suit the prepackaged database, there will be an issue in that Room does not allow the Primary Key to be nullable. As such you will need to either change the prepackaged database or change it before handing the database over to Room, this could be via the prepackagedDatabaseCallback.

as suggested and shown changing the prepackaged database via an SQLite tool is relatively easy.


see How do I use Room's prepackagedDatabaseCallback?

Suggested (the easiest/less complex) Solution
It would probably be easier to use an SQLite tool to change the database. This could be undertaken by:-

Creating the required @Entity annotated classes for the tables.
Defining the @Entity annotated classes in the entities parameter of the @Database annotation.
Successfully compile the project.
In the Android View of Android Studion locate the Java (generated) folder.
Find the file/class (in one of the sub-folders) that is the same name as the @Database annotated class but suffixed with _Impl.
In the file locate the createAllTables method/function, there will be a line of SQL for each component (table/index/view) that Room will build. This SQL is EXACTLY what Room expects.
In the SQLite tool on a per component basis (not room_master_table):-

rename the existing component to a suitable name (ALTER TABLE ? RENAME TO ?)

indexes can be ignored as they will be renamed


create the component using the respective copied SQL

Copy the data from the renamed original table to the newly created table.

This could be as easy as INSERT INTO ? SELECT * FROM ?, but some data manipulation may be required, as may coding specific column names


drop the renamed table (suggest ensuring that you have backups of the SQLite database).





The above is basically the same if you used the prePackagedDatabase callback.

Example/Demo
First consider a database based upon the Expected/Found message as created in an SQLite tool (Navicat in this example), as per:-
/*
    Schema of Prepackaged activities tables as Room found it:-
Found:
  TableInfo{name='activities', 
    columns={
    activityId=Column{name='acti vityId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='undefined'}, 
    ownerId=Column{name='ownerId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, 
    title=Column{name='title', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, 
    desc=Column{name='desc', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, 
    visibility=Column{name='visibility', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, 
    latitude=Column{name='latitude', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, 
    longitude=Column{name='longitude', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, 
    emojiId=Column{name='emojiId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}}, 
    
    foreignKeys=[
        ForeignKey{referenceTable='user', 
        onDelete='NO ACTION +', 
        onUpdate='NO ACTION', 
            columnNames=[ownerId], referenceColumnNames=[id]}], 
    indices=[]}
*/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `activities`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS activities (
    `activity Id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    `ownerId` INTEGER,
    `title` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `desc` TEXT,
    `visibility` INTEGER,
    `latitude` INTEGER,
    `longitude` INTEGER,
    `emojId` INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (ownerId) REFERENCES `users`(id)
);
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (null,'U1'),(null,'U2'),(null,'U3');
INSERT INTO `activities` VALUES
    (null,1,'Title for O1','Owner 1 description',1,100,300,1),
    (null,2,'Title for O2','Owner 2 description',0,200,400,2),
    (null,3,'Title for O3','Owner 3 description',0,200,400,3),
    (null,1,'Title for O4',null,1,100,300,1),
    (null,2,'Ttile for O5','Owner 2 description',1,200,400,2),
    (null,3,'Title for O6',null,1,200,400,3)
;
SELECT * FROM activities JOIN users ON activities.ownerId=users.id

/* EXTRA TO CONVERT ABOVE FOR ROOM (to be added)*/

The output from the SELECT being:-

And the following App code based upon your question:-
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        /* Force Open of Database (getting instance will not open the database)*/
        db.openHelper.writableDatabase
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(db.query("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master;",null))
    }
}

@Entity
data class Users(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int,
    val name: String?
)

@Entity(
    tableName = "activities",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Users::class, // Assuming your user entity class is named User
            parentColumns = ["id"],
            childColumns = ["ownerId"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE, // Correct onDelete action
        )
    ]
)
data class Activities(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)val activityId: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "ownerId") val ownerId: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title") @NotNull val title: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "desc") val desc: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "visibility") val visibility: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "latitude")  val latitude: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "longitude")  val longitude: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "emojiId") val emojiId: Int?,
    @Ignore val actLabel: String="", // New column
    @Ignore val actDate: Int=0, // New column
    @Ignore @NotNull val actLocation: String="", // New column
) {
    constructor(activityId: Int, ownerId: Int?, title: String,desc: String?,visibility: Int,latitude: Int,longitude: Int ,emojiId: Int?) : this(
        activityId = activityId,
        ownerId = ownerId,
        title = title,
        desc = desc,
        visibility = visibility,
        latitude = latitude,
        longitude = longitude,
        emojiId = emojiId,
        actLabel = "",
        actDate = 0,
        actLocation = ""
    )
}

@Database(entities = [Users::class,Activities::class], exportSchema = false, version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase?=null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance==null) {
                instance=Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries() /* for brevity */
                    .createFromAsset("prepackaged_unconverted.xxx")
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
        val pp = object: PrepackagedDatabaseCallback(){
            override fun onOpenPrepackagedDatabase(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                super.onOpenPrepackagedDatabase(db)
                Log.d("PPCALLBACK","PrePackagaedDatabase Callback Invoked!!!!!")
            }
        }
    }

}


note the User class is just a guess as it is not included in the question

note that the prepackeddatabase has been copied into the assets folder from where it was saved by the SQLite Tool (ensuring that the -wal file did not exist (in the case of Navicat by closing Navicat))

Note the constructor added to suit so that Room can build an Activities object without the @Ignored fields (you may wish to adapt this to suit)



When run, then the issue is encountered as per:-
database has an invalid schema: activities(a.a.so78643363kotlinroomprepackagedexample.Activities).
     Expected:
    TableInfo{name='activities', columns={activityId=Column{name='activityId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='undefined'}, emojiId=Column{name='emojiId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, visibility=Column{name='visibility', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, latitude=Column{name='latitude', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, ownerId=Column{name='ownerId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, title=Column{name='title', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, desc=Column{name='desc', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, longitude=Column{name='longitude', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}}, foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='Users', onDelete='CASCADE +', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[ownerId], referenceColumnNames=[id]}], indices=[]}
     Found:
    TableInfo{name='activities', columns={activity Id=Column{name='activity Id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='undefined'}, ownerId=Column{name='ownerId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, title=Column{name='title', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, desc=Column{name='desc', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, visibility=Column{name='visibility', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, latitude=Column{name='latitude', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, longitude=Column{name='longitude', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, emojId=Column{name='emojId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}}, foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='users', onDelete='NO ACTION +', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[ownerId], referenceColumnNames=[id]}], indices=[]}

Converting
First the EXPECTED SQL for the activities table is copied (note the users table is known to be OK) from the generated Java e.g.



In the SQLite tool the following is used (i.e. the above plus the EXTRA) as per:-
....
/* EXTRA TO CONVERT ABOVE FOR ROOM (to be added)*/

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS activities_original; /* Just in case */
ALTER TABLE activities RENAME TO activities_original;
/*>>>>>>>>>> COPIED FROM generated Java <<<<<<<<<<*/
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `activities` (`activityId` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `ownerId` INTEGER, `title` TEXT NOT NULL, `desc` TEXT, `visibility` INTEGER NOT NULL, `latitude` INTEGER NOT NULL, `longitude` INTEGER NOT NULL, `emojiId` INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(`ownerId`) REFERENCES `Users`(`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE );
INSERT INTO activities SELECT * FROM activities_original;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS activities_original;
SELECT * FROM activities JOIN users ON activities.ownerId=users.id;

The SQlite file is saved and again copied into the assets (in this case to co-exist with the previous unconverted) e.g.:-


obviously you would not distribute the App with both assets

The .createFromAsset invocation in the App code is amended to utilise the changed asset file :-
instance=Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"the_database.db")
.allowMainThreadQueries() /* for brevity */
//.createFromAsset("prepackaged_unconverted.xxx")
.createFromAsset("prepackaged_converted.yyy", pp)
.build()
and the App is then run, culminating in the following output in the log:-
2024-06-20 10:48:04.386 D/PPCALLBACK: PrePackagaedDatabase Callback Invoked!!!!!
2024-06-20 10:48:04.476 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@ae23707
2024-06-20 10:48:04.477 I/System.out: 0 {
2024-06-20 10:48:04.477 I/System.out:    type=table
2024-06-20 10:48:04.477 I/System.out:    name=sqlite_sequence
2024-06-20 10:48:04.477 I/System.out:    tbl_name=sqlite_sequence
2024-06-20 10:48:04.477 I/System.out:    rootpage=3
2024-06-20 10:48:04.477 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence(name,seq)
2024-06-20 10:48:04.478 I/System.out: }
2024-06-20 10:48:04.478 I/System.out: 1 {
2024-06-20 10:48:04.479 I/System.out:    type=table
2024-06-20 10:48:04.480 I/System.out:    name=users
2024-06-20 10:48:04.480 I/System.out:    tbl_name=users
2024-06-20 10:48:04.480 I/System.out:    rootpage=4
2024-06-20 10:48:04.480 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE `users` (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, name TEXT)
2024-06-20 10:48:04.480 I/System.out: }
2024-06-20 10:48:04.481 I/System.out: 2 {
2024-06-20 10:48:04.481 I/System.out:    type=table
2024-06-20 10:48:04.481 I/System.out:    name=activities
2024-06-20 10:48:04.482 I/System.out:    tbl_name=activities
2024-06-20 10:48:04.483 I/System.out:    rootpage=5
2024-06-20 10:48:04.483 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE `activities` (`activityId` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `ownerId` INTEGER, `title` TEXT NOT NULL, `desc` TEXT, `visibility` INTEGER NOT NULL, `latitude` INTEGER NOT NULL, `longitude` INTEGER NOT NULL, `emojiId` INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(`ownerId`) REFERENCES `Users`(`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE )
2024-06-20 10:48:04.483 I/System.out: }
2024-06-20 10:48:04.483 I/System.out: 3 {
2024-06-20 10:48:04.483 I/System.out:    type=table
2024-06-20 10:48:04.483 I/System.out:    name=android_metadata
2024-06-20 10:48:04.483 I/System.out:    tbl_name=android_metadata
2024-06-20 10:48:04.483 I/System.out:    rootpage=6
2024-06-20 10:48:04.483 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
2024-06-20 10:48:04.483 I/System.out: }
2024-06-20 10:48:04.483 I/System.out: 4 {
2024-06-20 10:48:04.483 I/System.out:    type=table
2024-06-20 10:48:04.483 I/System.out:    name=room_master_table
2024-06-20 10:48:04.484 I/System.out:    tbl_name=room_master_table
2024-06-20 10:48:04.484 I/System.out:    rootpage=7
2024-06-20 10:48:04.484 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE room_master_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,identity_hash TEXT)
2024-06-20 10:48:04.484 I/System.out: }
2024-06-20 10:48:04.484 I/System.out: <<<<<

i.e.

The PrePackagedDatabase callback has been called (not that is has done anything, but it could be used to convert using similar executions of the SQL used for the conversion)
Room has not  found any discrepancies aka it has found what was expected and has thus allowed the query of the schema (sqlite_master)

note that room_master_table has been created by Room.



